# Validate "sequelize" column of one model based on other column in different model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, psql

I have two models let's say "Person" which has first_name, last_name columns.
The second one would be "Student" which has other properties.
I want to validate that if a new Student is created, then "first_name" is not null.
But I want to do that when I define the model. is That possible?

```
const Student = sequelize.define("student", {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      validate: {
        isValid() {
          //here I want to validate if Person.first_name is not null, and if it is I want to throw new Error.
        }
      }
    },
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are `Student` and `Person` models related to each other?

Comment: Separate your validations into a file then use it everywhere you want

Comment: Theres a foreign key from the student table to the person which is person_id. I want to allow add new records to the student table only if first_name is not null. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone still looking for this solution

```
const Student = sequelize.define("student", {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      validate: {
        isValid(curVal, next) {
          sequelize.models.Person <--- your other table model
          .findOne({ where: { col1: curVal } }) <--- add where clause as you need
          .then((result) => {
            if (!result) {
              throw new Error('Invalid Person!');
            }
            return next();
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            return next(err);
          });
        }
      }
    },
}
```